# Is it correct to omit 一起 in sentences like 我跟我的朋友一起去?

Tags: grammar

In a sentence like

> 我跟我的朋友一起去
> I go with my friend

Is it correct to omit 一起? I mean, should 跟 always be accompanied by 一起?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides 'with', 跟 also has the meaning of 'follow'. Therefore,  一起 (together) can only be omitted when the context clearly suggests it doesn't mean 'follow'

Example:

- 我跟我的朋友都不懂滑水 -- 跟 here clearly means 'and' because it is indicated by 都, therefore, adding 一起 in the sentence is ungrammatical (redundant with 都)
- 我跟我的朋友一起去滑水 clearly means "I went water skiing with my friends (together)" - *'together' can be omitted in English*
- 我跟我的朋友去學滑水 could mean "I went to learn water skiing with my friend " (you and your friends go learn together) or "I followed my friend to learn water skiing" (your friends take you somewhere to teach you)
- 跟 in 我跟我的朋友去 could mean 'with' or 'follow' if you omit 一起. That would create ambiguity
- 我在美國跟專家學滑水 clearly means: "I learned water skiing from an expert in the U.S." adding 一起 is illogical

Answer (score 2):

我跟你去 means *I will follow you*, whilst 我跟你一起去 means *I will go with you together*.

我跟你去: It somehow imply that you take the lead. It might be that you go first, then I go after you.

我跟你一起去: you two go together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 一起 can be omitted.

However, the translation of the original sentence should be "I and my friend go together", as 跟 = 和 in this sentence.